# The ribbon item 'Foo' is dependent on ribbon control id='Bar' when Hiding Button

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, ribbon, microsoft-dynamics

I'm trying to hide the 'Add Existing' button for a custom entity subgrid on the Contact form. My steps so far;

- Add Contact entity to solution
- Export solution and load up `customisations.xml` in VS2010
- Add following to `CustomAction` node

  ```
  <HideCustomAction HideActionId="sample.Mscrm.SubGrid.new_gppractice.AddExistingAssoc.HideAction" Location="Mscrm.SubGrid.new_gppractice.AddExistingAssoc" />
  <HideCustomAction HideActionId="sample.Mscrm.SubGrid.new_gppractice.AddExistingStandard.HideAction" Location="Mscrm.SubGrid.new_gppractice.AddExistingStandard" />
  ```
- Save, reimport

Upon trying to reimport I get the following error:

```
The ribbon item 'sample.Mscrm.SubGrid.new_gppractice.AddExistingAssoc.HideAction' is dependent on ribbon control id='Mscrm.SubGrid.new_gppractice.AddExistingAssoc'
The ribbon item 'sample.Mscrm.SubGrid.new_gppractice.AddExistingStandard.HideAction' is dependent on ribbon control id='Mscrm.SubGrid.new_gppractice.AddExistingStandard'
```

Any ideas why I'm getting these errors?

Comment: I am unbelievably stupid. The entity name is wrong. At least I didn't make a question on stack to broadcast such a stupid mistake. Oh wait...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't say I have an actual explanation for why this has failed.

However I can suggest trying: [Ribbon Workbench](http://www.develop1.net/public/page/Ribbon-Workbench-for-Dynamics-CRM-2011.aspx), it makes these sort of customizations significantly easier.

Comment: I like this as it sits inside CRM, compared to some other tools I've seen that sit outside of it.

Comment: Yeah, the author deserves a medal.

Comment: Except the tool can also cause this error. Also, it downloads and re-deploys the solution to the server so if you have multiple developers working on the same environment you can undo customisations and cause general mayhem.